# SharePoint adding 2 zeros to the percentage values in my list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, administration, json-formatting

In my SharePoint list, I have a 'Number' column with the 'Show as percentage' option checked.

Unfortunately, for each value in this column, SharePoint adds two zeros, so instead of '100%', it shows '10000%'.

I suspect SharePoint automatically multiplies the value entered by the user by 100 to display it as a percentage. I find it plain stupid if that's indeed the case.

How can I fix this? I don't want SharePoint to add two zeros to my values.

Comment: Use simple number column without checking 'Show as percentage' option and add `%` suffix from column settings. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Where do you see `10000%` exactly, in list view or in flow/app, etc.?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, thank you for your response. It's about the list, no flows or apps involved.

Comment: I just tested this at my end and it works fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA0CY.png

Comment: I added the suffix using the following formula:

`{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "='@currentField' + '%'"
}`

But it's adding "%" to all fields in the column, even if there is no value at all.

Comment: Try using JSON given in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint stores actual values ranging from 0 to 1 for a Number column with 'Show as percentage' option checked in backend.

**Solutions**:

If you are using SharePoint Online modern experience list and you want to show the numbers in "Number" column with `%` (Example: 100%), try this:

1. Go to your SharePoint list
2. Create a number column with column settings like (without 'Show as percentage' option checked):

   [image]

**Output**:

[image]

---

**If above solution is not working for you**:

1. Create a simple number column without 'Show as percentage' option checked and without adding `%` suffix from column settings.
2. Use JSON column formatting like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if(@currentField, @currentField + '%', '')"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, the JSON you provided works perfectly!